# How do I access Rust documentation?

Tags: firefox, snap, rust

I installed Rust from the rustlang.org website. I tried to look at the Book:

```
rustup doc --book
```

This results in an "Access to the file was denied" error in Firefox.

I assumed this was a snap issue, and asked in their forum. Got crickets.

So, I'm asking here. Maybe someone has figured out how to make Firefox open /home/me/.rustup/whatever.

Here is the output of `snap connections | grep personal-files`:

```
personal-files            firefox:dot-mozilla-firefox     :personal-files                  -
```

Here is a screenshot of Firefox telling me it cannot access the file...

[image: Firefox error message]

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ works for me with chromium.

Comment: @chili555 The website works fine for me too. `rustup doc` does not. That is my question.

Comment: Your output of `snap connections | grep personal-files` is both correct and matches the default setting. Your Firefox snap DOES have permission to access hidden files in your /home dir. I think we need the complete, exact error message.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -laR /home/iain/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/doc/rust/html/` ?

Comment: The output of ls -laR is pretty long, there's lots of files and directories under there. In short, all the directories, starting with /home/iain/.rustup are owned by iain:iain, and have mode 775. All the files (html, woff2, js, css, etc, etc) are owned by iain:iain and have mode 644. Ask me again if you're looking for other info and really need 39000 lines of output to peruse. :)

Comment: This is getting tiresome. Folks on the snapcraft.io forum suggested I use CTRL-O to open individual files. But links don't work. I have to write down where the link goes and use CTRL-O to open the next page.

Comment: I tried reinstalling snap firefox in classic mode, but that doesn't work because the snap is intrinsically strictly confined.

Answer (score 4):

This does not work because the Firefox snap is not allowed access to `~/.rustup`, which is a 'hidden' directory because it starts with a dot.

As a workaround, you can do the following to move the real location of `~/.rustup` somewhere else. In this case we are moving it to `~/etc/rustup`.

Execute the following in a terminal.

1. `mkdir -p ~/etc`
2. `mv ~/.rustup ~/etc/rustup`
3. `ln -s ~/etc/rustup ~/.rustup`

Now `rustup doc` should work transparently.